# how do you port a mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I'm moving servers and I wish to keep my database what are the step by step commands to move the entire database or at least an entire table with all the rows?

Comment: Have you even considered using google before posting?

Answer (score 0):

`$>mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> <databasename> > dump.sql`

... move file to new box

`$>mysql -u <user> -p<password> <databasename> < dump.sql`

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to get a backup from entire database using phpmyadmin export section at old server
secondly you need to import the backup file at new server phpmyadmin import section.
you can define a new user for imported database by user privileges section of phpmyadmin